# Creating very large image files with BufferedImage, strange issues depending on compilation and computer (-Xmx does not work)

Tags: java, memory, jvm

Just to follow up on here: [Creating very large image files with BufferedImage, strange issues depending on compilation and computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961795/creating-very-large-image-files-with-bufferedimage-strange-issues-depending-on-c)

I still have the issue and I did try the Xmx command line to make sure the JVM had at least 1024m of RAM, I put the parametere in as both -Xmx1024m and -Xmx 1024m but neither worked.

Comment: define "never worked": The VM won't start because you don't have 1024+ megs to start the VM? have you put in calls to Runtime.maxMemory to see that you've set it correctly?  did you put it before all of other settings?  or after your class name so it got interpreted as a command line to your application?

Comment: oh I meant it didn't fix the problem, it did add the memory though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is -Xmx1024m. Other then that, you didn't answer my question on the previous thread - you said you were showing the image (after creating it). When exactly do you get the exception? After showing it or after creating it? Do you re-create the image every time you want to display it? We need more information - post the code you're using to load and show the image, preferably an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: oh sorry I thought I mentioned after creating it, that was where I traced the error back to.

I get it the first time I create it, BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(58240, 1664, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Comment: Creating the image this way means it will take about ~390MB. This is still less then the 1024MB you gave the heap which means that either you have 2+ more images like this or something else is taking up the heap space. Other than that, you still haven't mentioned have you display it. It would also help if you gave us the output of java -version.

Comment: +1 for the SSCCE reference. That's my new watchword as of today